# css - On hover text, empty space in underline

Tags: html, css

The hover needs to be work on the div, so I put hover rule to the div. 
There is a bold number and text in it. If there is no "padding-right:1px" to the bold text, there is no problem, but when using it, the underline has an empty space on hover. I must use padding-right:1px.

Note: Using `&nbsp;` instead of "padding-right:1px" makes it too far, so its not a solution.

[image]

```css
.member:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="member">
  <b style="padding-right:1px">4</b> members
</div>
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Can you add a picture of what you are seeing?

Comment: I only see a "gap" between `4` and `members`. Is this what you are referring to?

Comment: I have added picture now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take this: `<b style="letter-spacing: 1px;">4</b> members` instead of the padding option. I made a fiddle, so you can see that it works: https://jsfiddle.net/1w31kp4o/

I hope this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Philipps solution is great, and probably the best for your current issue. Here are a few alternative approaches however.

#### Simple approach with `border-bottom`

```css
.member:hover {
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="member">
  <b style="padding-right:1px">4</b> members
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft55z9de/)

---

#### A more extreme approach with `:after`

This one is probably a bit overkill for what you want, but this offers some flexibility if you need that. You can for example adjust the distance of the underline by changing the `bottom` value, as well as other things of course, such as changing the underline thickness, color, etc etc...

```css
.member {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
.member:hover:after {
  content: "";
  width: 100%;
  height: 1px;
  background: black;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="member">
  <b style="padding-right:1px">4</b> members
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ft55z9de/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use thin space (`&#8201;`):

Try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hkb60qnu/

Answer (score 1):

This will make it for you. It is a small tweak to your approach:

**HTML**

```
<div class="member">
  <b>4</b> members
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.member {
  display: inline-block;  
}

.member:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

[Here's a CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ORgpBP) for you to take a look